# Why is the ".sbs" TLD listed as "Termination in Process" with ICANN?

Tags: domains, icann

Today I was reading about the `.sbs` domain on https://icannwiki.org/.sbs.

It has been available for everyone since 15 June 2021 for general purposes.

At the top of the ICANNWiki page, there is a table that shows the domain status as "Termination in Process".

What does "Termination in Process" actually mean?

I have a `.sbs` domain, does this means that I will not able to use/renew that domain anymore?

Comment: Contrary to its name `icannwiki.org`  is **NOT** run by ICANN, and hence is not authoritative at all. It is like Wikipedia, but for ICANN content. So don't expect it to be up to date always, nor to be correct 100% all the time on everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That document appears to be out of date. The short answer is that your `.sbs` domains aren't going away, so don't worry.

Here's the timeline for `.sbs`, as best as I can piece it together:

- On 7 November 2014, *Special Broadcasting Service Corporation* registered the `.sbs` TLD with ICANN, for private use.
- On 22 April 2020, *Special Broadcasting Service Corporation* sent ICANN an intent to terminate the `.sbs` TLD.
- On 12 June 2020, ICANN made a preliminary determination that the `.sbs` TLD would not be handed over to a new operator.
- On 12 July 2020, ICANN finalized the decision and terminated the `.sbs` TLD.
- On 06 May 2021, The [ShortDot](https://shortdot.bond/) domain registry posted a [press release](https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/shortdots-new-sbs-domain-extension-is-all-set-for-a-sunrise-launch-on-may-6-for-trademark-holders-301285428.html) stating that it acquired the `.sbs` TLD and is launching it as a gTLD, with registrations available immediately for trademark holders.
- In June 2021, the `.sbs` domain went into general availability. Now, anyone can register a `.sbs` domain.

So in summary, a company registered `.sbs` for private use in 2014, relinquished it in 2020 ("Termination"), then another company picked it up in 2021 to offer it as a gTLD to the public.

Your domain name is a new 2021 `.sbs`, registered with ShortDot through your registrar. The "Termination" of `.sbs` at the old registrar was back in 2020, and is old news.

Comment: ICANN contract on 2021-02-21 about the change: https://itp.cdn.icann.org/en/files/registry-agreements/sbs/sbs-assign-pdf-22feb21-en.pdf